# php post method from select option with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

php code

```
if(empty($_POST) === false)
{
    $required_fields = array('s_group', 's_choice');
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
    {

        if(empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true)
        {
            $error = 'All * fields are required';
            break 1;
        }

    }


    if(empty($error) === true)
    {
        echo $_POST['s_group'];
        echo $_POST['s_choice'];
        echo $_POST['choice1'];
        echo $_POST['choice2'];
    }
}

echo $error;
```

This is html code

```
<form action="create_room.php" method="post" name="form1">
<select name="s_group">
    <option value=""><-- Please Select Item --></option>
    <?
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM room_group_options ORDER BY op_id";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
    while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
    {
    ?>
    <option value="<?=$objResult["op_id"];?>"><?=$objResult["group"];?></option>
    <?
    }
    ?>
  </select>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

 <p>Number of Choice :
 <select id="pagelist" name = "s_choice">
     <option value=""><-- Please Select Item --></option>
     <option value="twoChoices">2 Choices</option>
     <option value="threeChoices">3 Choices</option>
     <option value="fourChoices">4 Choices</option>
     <option value="fiveChoices">5 Choices</option>
 </select>

 <div id="twoChoices" style="display:none">

  Insert your choice<br>
  1:<input type="text" name="choice1" /><br />
  2:<input type="text" name="choice2" /><br /> 

 </div>

 <div id="threeChoices" style="display:none">

    Insert your choice<br>
    1:<input type="text" name="choice1" /><br />
    2:<input type="text" name="choice2" /><br /> 
    3:<input type="text" name="choice3" /><br /> 

 </div>


  <script language="javascript">
  $("#pagelist").change(function()
  {
    var viewID = $("#pagelist option:selected").val();
    $("#pagelist option").each(function()
    {
        var hideID = $(this).val();
        $("#"+hideID).hide();
    });
    $("#"+viewID).show();   
  });
</script>

<input type="submit" name "submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

I am a PHP newbie. After fill all blank, selected choice and hit submit button the value from s_group and s_choice are in $_POST but choice1 and choice2 aren't come.

How can I get these value?

Comment: aren't they disabled? display:none

Comment: why not just to use: $("#pagelist").val() to send!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the following code
Insert your choice

```
1:<input type="text" name="choice1" value = ""/><br />
2:<input type="text" name="choice2" value = ""/><br />
```

```
Insert your choice<br>
1:<input type="text" name="choice3" value = ""/><br />
2:<input type="text" name="choice4" value = ""/><br /> 
3:<input type="text" name="choice5" value = ""/><br />
```

And dont duplicate your names of choices. Make your javascript in such a way that it will show/hide choice3, choice4 and choice 5 button on pagelist change.

Answer (score 1):

Make only one instance of text input button Choice1, choice2 ... and so on and hide/show individual text input via javascript on change of pagelist. You will get your variables in your post.